# Get filtered row in a gridview

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to get the filtered rows from a gridview control?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you have a gridview with filtering enabled, and you filtered the data and now you want to get the rows, that are currently displayed?

You could iterate over the Rows-Collection of the GridView - this should contain all visible rows.